# android OpenSSLSessionImpl finalize SEGV_MAPERR crash

Tags: android, openssl, java-native-interface, okhttp

Recently we rewrite our Android application from bottom to up(contains lots of java and native code), maybe change some native library init order;

we use OkHttp as our network library.

OkHttp version: 3.10.0.1

OkHttpClient

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
builder.readTimeout(IO_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
builder.writeTimeout(IO_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
builder.addInterceptor(new OkHttpRequestInterceptor());
builder.dns(dns);
if (ToolUtils.isMainProcess(context)) {
    builder.cookieJar(new CustomedCookieJar(CookieHandler.getDefault()));
}
builder.followRedirects(true);
return builder.build();
```

Peoples who upgrade from older version to the refactored version may met OpenSSLSessionImpl crash,(influence ~5% users)

It takes our few man, few weeks to resolve the bug, but all failed.

below is some of OpenSSLSessionImpl crashes stack

```
SIGSEGV(SEGV_MAPERR)


1 #00 pc 0003de92 /system/lib/libcrypto.so [armeabi-v7a]
2 #01 pc 0003deed /system/lib/libcrypto.so [armeabi-v7a]
3 #02 pc 0003dd1d /system/lib/libcrypto.so [armeabi-v7a]
4 #03 pc 0003dd1d /system/lib/libcrypto.so [armeabi-v7a]
5 #04 pc 0003dc59 /system/lib/libcrypto.so (ASN1_item_free+20) [armeabi-v7a]
6 #05 pc 0007122f /system/lib/libcrypto.so (sk_pop_free+22) [armeabi-v7a]
7 #06 pc 0001c02b /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_SESSION_free+66) [armeabi-v7a]
8 #07 pc 00083b0d /system/framework/arm/boot-conscrypt.oat (oatexec+64269) [armeabi]
9 java:
10 com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSessionImpl.finalize(OpenSSLSessionImpl.java:486)
11 java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
12 java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
13 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

or

```
    1   #00 pc 0005f9aa /system/lib/libcrypto.so (sk_free+5) [armeabi-v7a]
2   #01 pc 0001751f /system/lib/libssl.so [armeabi-v7a]
3   #02 pc 0001831f /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_free+82) [armeabi-v7a]
4   #03 pc 024f90a5 /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (oatexec+2674853) [armeabi]
5   java:
6   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.free(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1163)
7   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1142)
8   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1126)
9   okhttp3.internal.c.closeQuietly(Util.java:125)
10  okhttp3.internal.connection.c.b(RealConnection.java:347)
11  okhttp3.internal.connection.c.a(RealConnection.java:274)
12  okhttp3.internal.connection.c.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
13  okhttp3.internal.connection.f.a(StreamAllocation.java:258)
14  okhttp3.internal.connection.f.a(StreamAllocation.java:136)
15  okhttp3.internal.connection.f.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:115)
16  okhttp3.internal.connection.a.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
17  okhttp3.internal.b.g.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
18  okhttp3.internal.b.g.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
19  okhttp3.internal.a.a.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
20  okhttp3.internal.b.g.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
```

This kind of crash doesn't focus on any specific Android version(from 4 to 8) and any android device(multiple android manufacturer);

As crash reports shown, average 1 time per user maybe met, we did not have reproduce it util now, and can not understand what situation will cause it,  so there does not have code snippets.

any buddy got some clues? or face this kind of situation before.

thanks in advance;

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the OkHttp source code, but the one thing that comes to mind is that if you're using OpenSSL on multiple threads you may have to specify [some callbacks](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/CRYPTO_set_locking_callback.html) to make it thread-safe (depending on the OpenSSL version used).

Comment: thanks your reply, I checked our code base again and didn't find any code relate with OpenSSL or something like this.
this crash maybe cased by dangling pointer of some native library. but all crash focused on OpenSSL it's wired.

Comment: Same here. Already working on this issues for weeks, still no answer. :(